# Proper way to pass config properties loaded by Spring to JSF world

Tags: spring, jsf

I have a duplicated configuration file under **WEB-INF** directory, called **configDEV.properties** and **configPRO.properties** (one for development environment, and the other for production environment).

I load the proper file thanks to these Spring declaration and this Tomcat launch parameter:

```
<context:property-placeholder 
        location="WEB-INF/config${project.environment}.properties" />

-Dproject.environment=PRO
(or –Dproject.environment=DEV)
```

Then, in a **servlet listener** (called StartListener) I do the following, in order to allow **JSF** to access these properties, in the managed beans, and in the jsp views. (In concrete, we are going to play with a property called *cfg.skin.richSelector*).

```
public class StartListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        //Environment properties
        Map<String, String> vblesEntorno = System.getenv();

        //Project properties
        String entorno = vblesEntorno.get("project.environment");
        String ficheroPropiedades = "/WEB-INF/config" + entorno + ".properties";
        try {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.load(sc.getResourceAsStream(ficheroPropiedades));

            setSkinRichSelector(sc, props.getProperty("cfg.skin.richSelector"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //...
        }
    }

    private void setSkinRichSelector(ServletContext sc, String skinRichSelector) {
        sc.setInitParameter("cfg.skin.richSelector", skinRichSelector); 
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {}

}
```

In a JSF managed bean:

```
public class ThemeSwitcher implements Serializable {

    private boolean richSelector;

    public ThemeSwitcher() {

        richSelector = Boolean.parseBoolean(
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getInitParameter("cfg.skin.richSelector"));

        if (richSelector) {
            //do A
        } else {
            //do B
        }

    }

    //getters & setters

}
```

In a xhtml page:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="#{themeSwitcher.richSelector}">
        <ui:include src="/app/comun/includes/themeSwitcherRich.xhtml"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <ui:include src="/app/comun/includes/themeSwitcher.xhtml"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

All of this WORKS OK, but I want to ask the experts if it is the most suitable way to do that, or if this could be simplified in some way???

Thanks in advance for your hints and advices

Comment: Which version of Spring and JSF are you using?

Comment: Spring 3.1.1 & JSF 2.0 (Mojarra 2.0.6?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which version of Spring you are using. If it happens to be newest Spring 3.1, you can take advantage of `@Profile`:

[Springsource Blog](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/)

[Springsource reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html#d0e1293)

Comment: After posting this question some priority tasks become. So, for now we have no time to try your suggestions. Maybe next week. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Although I didn’t try it yet, it is supposed to be the correct answer, so I give you the Green mark

Answer (score 1):

Leave the property-placeholder in your applicationContext.xml if you are using it in your spring beans.

Configure a context init param in your web.xml like this:

```
   <context-param>
      <param-name>envProp</param-name>
      <param-value>${project.environment}</param-value>
   </context-param>
```

Also move the properties file under some package in your classpath (Note: Due to this change you need to locate the resource in the application context using classpath*: prefix)

and then you can load the bundle in your JSF page like this:

```
<f:loadBundle basename="com.examples.config#{initParam['envProp']}" var="msgs"/>
```

and use something like this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{msgs.cfg.skin.richSelector}" />
```

But instead of setting the system property like this configure ProjectStage via JNDI as mentioned by Ryan Lubke in his [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/rlubke/entry/jsf_2_0_new_feature2) so that you can use the same property even for javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE context parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but first two paragraphs are un-negotiable for us: "I have a duplicated configuration file under WEB-INF directory, called configDEV.properties and configPRO.properties (one for development environment, and the other for production environment).
I load the proper file thanks to these Spring declaration and this Tomcat launch parameter"

Comment: ya then just duplicating the files will be the best way to do it and use like above.